# Android RecyclerView below Toolbar

Tags: android, toolbar, android-recyclerview

I have a custom RecyclerView and a toolbar which hide when scrolling down and appears when scrolling up. I have a problem about the position of RecyclerView, it is below the Toolbar, I use the behaviour but it seems not working.

My xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: why do you have both RecyclerView and ViewPager layout_width and layout_height as "match_parent" ?

Comment: Are you looking for a collapsing toolbar layout? where the toolbar expands to fit a header and then collapses into the toolbar? If you are not needing the collapsing toolbar layout you probably do not need the AppBarLayout. If you just want to hide and show the toolbar you can do that with a simple OnScrollListener.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView 
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I have removed the ViewPager and added scrolling behavior to RecyclerView

Comment: That's working but there is another problem. If I scroll down and go in another app when the bar is hidden when I open again my app the toolbar will be white without everything.

Comment: It worked! But there is a line which I can see. How does it do the trick and how can I solve in a better way?

Comment: @SamikBandyopadhyay what's the problem?

Comment: AppBarLayout & Toolbar inside the RecyclerView?

Comment: @LangustenGustel They are below the `RecyclerView` (in the xml above, in actual layout the toolbar is still placed at the top). Take a closer look.

Comment: I went with adding `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` to the RecyclerView and also to the FrameLayout that is directly under the CoordinatorLayout. In my case, without this attribute, the framelayout starts directly behind the toolbar and so it appears that the recycler view is the one with the problem.

Comment: Can you add an explanation to this? To the inexperienced user, this just looks like another code block to copy into their application (google "Cargo Cult Programming").

Comment: @JL2210 The last line basically described what I did with OP's code. They had an useless `ViewPager` in their layout so firstly I removed it (because you can't have both `RecyclerView` and `ViewPager` fill the entire screen - only one allowed - and OP was asking about `RecyclerView`). Next thing I did was adding a property `app:layout_behavior` to the `RecyclerView` which basically made the `Toolbar` aware of whether the `RecyclerView` is being scrolled up or down, so it could show and hide itself accordingly.

Answer (score 49):

If Adding a scrolling behavior does not fix your issue

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

**THEN TRY THIS**

I had to give padding to recyclerview which is equivalent to the toolbar/actionbar(app bar) height.

```
  android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
```

add the above line to the recyclerview xml file

Comment: This trick works but while the scroll view scrolls and the appbar layout gets hidden then the padding looks odd.

Comment: could you provide more detail as i didnt face this issue, screen shot would be ideal

Comment: The best answer so far.

Comment: Thank you @Marlon glad it helped you

Comment: @SamikBandyopadhyay: maybe add `android:clipToPadding="false"`?

Comment: This trick will work for fixed toolbar but won't work with collapsible toolbar

Comment: Adding padding is akin to adding `if (xx != null) { xx.doSomething(); }` if the call to `xx.doSomething()` thew an NPE in production and you don’t know what the problem is, so instead you make it go away with a null check. Adding padding is hiding the problem or… more metaphorically speaking: dragging the problem down :)

Comment: @MartinMarconcini so what's the solution you have in mind

Comment: @war_Hero specify the correct layout behavior, as seen https://stackoverflow.com/a/38038536/2684 if that doesn’t work, there is a _different_ problem with the layout (or a bug in the framework, but I can assure you this works, because I’ve extensively used CoordinatorLayout & friends and have seen this issue every time I forget to add `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior”` to the offending widget).

Answer (score 15):

When I have included RecyclerView from another layout the same problem occurred. I added this following line on recyclerview and the problem no longer persists.

```
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

Missing this above line will make this problem.

Answer (score 7):

You need to add this attribute to your RecyclerView:

```
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

i.e.:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

Comment: If you use `FrameLayout` as a container in the main layout and there is a separate layout which includes `RecyclerView` - in this case, you should add `app:layout_behavior=` to the `FrameLayout` in the main layout!

Answer (score 3):

trying adding this line in the ReyclerView

```
  android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
```