# Toolbar is overriding the Recyclerview

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-toolbar

**Code for XML :-**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar1"
        layout="@layout/toolbar_standalone" />


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

> please help to correct the code. so toolbar does not overide the
> recycler view. I have laready tried this changes but not working
> perfectly.

```
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
```

Comment: It's expected behavior since you use `app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" ` instead of `app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar1"`

Comment: Thanks it working fine

Comment: I suggest you use CoordinatorLayout along with `app:layout_behavior`. See the answer for [Android RecyclerView below Toolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31306884/android-recyclerview-below-toolbar).

Answer (score 0):

you can width and height to layout

you can set the default action bar size

```
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
```

and use `layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf`

```
  <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar1"
        layout="@layout/toolbar_standalone"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"/>


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar1" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```